# Why an error is shown when setting up a new MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

[image: This error]

This error is shown when I was setting up a MySQL database. It was called test and I was sure the password is correct. The reason why I had MySQL questions before was because I migrated from an old computer to a new computer. What commands should I run to get rid of this issue? I had an MySQL project in hand... Thank you very much! (I just used Store in vault... >> Fill in password >> Store in vault >> Test connection... >> Enter password >> error)

Edit: [After I opened services, MySQL 80 is already up and running?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Qc8.png)

Comment: Is MYSQL server running?

Comment: @Ashok Yes. Given that I follow the exact same procedure and the result is identical, I do not feel the result is right.

Comment: Open services -- select MySQLxx service -- right click and hit start

Comment: @Ashok Sorry, but what should I click to "Open services"? (I am a MySQL newbie, of course)

Comment: click on start button in windows and search for services and then a screen will open and then you can check the MySQLxx service

Comment: @Ashok Updated the question to show the result, please check...

Comment: Try restarting it and also restart the workbench

Comment: @Ashok Still, no change...

Comment: Check is there any MYSQL Router in your services if yes then do start that

Comment: Even after restarting the workbench.

Comment: @Ashok I don't have that...

Comment: Do I need to flush privileges?

Comment: Can try that but I don't think it work

Comment: It didn't... What can I do?

Comment: open cmd and run this command `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306` and check whether you're getting a pwd prompt to not

Comment: @Ashok Yes, it does pop up.

Comment: Try to connect it with your pwd

Comment: @Ashok Still identical...

Comment: if it's denied then grant the permissions `GRANT ALL ON [DatabaseName].* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';`

Comment: @Ashok `'root' is not expected for this server version...`